# dform append elements to existing dfrom

Tags: jquery

i create this dform (http://daffl.github.io/jquery.dform/)

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/daffl/jquery.dform/master/dist/jquery.dform-1.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="container"></form>
</body>
<script>
jQuery("#container").dform({
    "type":"ul",
    "name":"ulxx",
    "id":"ulxx",
    "html":[
        {
            "type":"li",
            "html":"AAAA"
        }
    ]
});
//now i want append li tag
//tried...but don't work (create another ul with same id and name !!!!)
jQuery("#container").dform({
    "type":"ul",
    "name":"ulxx",
    "id":"ulxx",
    "html":[
        {
        "type":"li",
        "html":"BBBBBBBBBBB"
        }
    ]
});
</script>
```

### tried...but don't work (create another ul with same id and name !!!!)

```
jQuery("#container").dform("append",{
    "type":"ul",
    "name":"ulxx",
    "id":"ulxx",
    "html":[
        {
        "type":"li",
        "html":"BBBBBBBBBB"
        }
    ]
});
```

have you some idea? there is a "append" method but don't work